# facebook graph api

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get the facebook username using graph api. Here is what I got so far, but its not giving me any data back. please help .

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    var arr = 1101892195;
    var url = 'http://graph.facebook.com/' + arr;

    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        var items = [];
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            items.push('li id="' + key + '"' + val + '/li');
        });
        $('ul', {
            'class': 'my-new-list',
            html: items.join('')
        }).appendTo('body');
    });

});
```

Comment: Basically... There are hundreds of posts on this and plenty on SO too which answer it... all you need is to use the search box first...

Comment: I don't mind if u not helping but why criticizing on someone post? Ye I am not bother searching caz it allows everyone to post own question to get more specific answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is restriction of [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)
you can't do this with jquery

Proxy script:

```
<?php 
echo file_get_contents("http://graph.facebook.com/".$_GET['atr']);
?>
```

Modified jS:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    var arr = 1101892195;
    var url = 'proxy.php?atr=' + arr;

    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        var items = [];
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            items.push('li id="' + key + '"' + val + '/li');
        });
        $('ul', {
            'class': 'my-new-list',
            html: items.join('')
        }).appendTo('body');
    });

});
```

Comment: aww. is there any other way round to do this? I just want to the username for about 10k users :(

Comment: Reason: Use the javascript SDK to get the data and same origin is no longer the issue... Therefore, it is not a valid answer either.

Comment: but my answer is correct, I told that it isn't achieveable with jQuery and I posted better solution.

Comment: Valid, after you edited, your answer is valid... I will remove the downvote if it means that much to you...

Answer (score 0):

It would be alot simpler using the Facebook javascript SDK.  If you are only trying to get basic public information, you won't need to have the user authenticate or even specify an app id.

**Here is a full example:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<a href="#" onclick="getUser('1101892195');return false;">Get User Info</a>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
 function getUser(id) {  
    FB.api('/' + id,  function(response) {
        alert('Full response: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
        alert('User: ' + response.name);
      }
    );
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```